# Blazor WebAssembly app tries to load script from `/_vs/browserLink` but it doesn't exist there

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging, hot-reload

My Blazor Web Assembly app in .NET 7 runs well when I use `dotnet run`, but when I run it from Visual Studio, I get in the browser console:

```
The script from “https://localhost:5008/_vs/browserLink” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

Of course, it is trying to load a js script from `/_vs/browserLink` but it doesn't exist.  I do not have a reference to BrowserLink anywhere in my project, and I don't have the browserlink Nuget package either.

1. Is Visual Studio injecting this automatically?
2. How do I figure out why is it failing? How do I make it work or stop trying?
3. BrowserLink is unrelated to Hot Reload, right? Do I even want to use BrowserLink?

This happens in both debugging and running without debugging, on Kestrel.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Szalapski, how do you run on Visual Studio? Run without debugging or Run with debugging? If run with debugging, where did you run, on IIS EXPRESS or kestrel? Any way, all of the options I have tried and do not get the error in browser console. What is your project like? Have you tried to create a new pure Blazor WebAssembly app?

Comment: This happens in both run without debugging and run with debugging, on Kestrel.  This doesn't happen with a new app, but how do I troubleshoot my existing app?  What is this _vs/browserLink script and what is making it attempt for it in the first place?

Comment: Hi @Patrick Szalapski,This script related to BrowserLink, and for the blazor webassembly app, it use and inject by default. Not sure why your project cannot work, as you said the new project works fine, also in my side it works fine. You can have a try to disabale BrowserLink like [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/browser-link-cannot-be-disabled/1582653#T-N1608441) to see if the error disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to .NET 7.0.1 (.NET SDK 7.0.101) and no longer have the trouble.  Not sure if it was really just a bug fix or if something else changed.